# Execute the function after all animations in queue done

Tags: jquery, animation, queue

I use jQuery animation queue to perform jumping animations of a character. I want to judge if the character succeed after he performs all the animations. But the function is always executed before he finished the animation. Is there a listener to judge if all animations in queue were done?

```
            $('.character').dequeue("myAnimation");

            if(self.currentlocation >= this.totalStep){
                while($('.character').is(":animated")){
                   setTimeout(function(){}, 500)
                }
                alert('win!');
                self.success();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about animations set using jQuery, the code would be as simple as that:

```
$('.character').promise().done(function(){
    // all animations for this matched set are done
});
```

### See example